# Cannot swap tiles with units

Tags: civilization-6

I have an archer on Hill (Woods) and an archer on Hill (Rainforest). Both have full amount of moves available (the turn just started) but I cannot swap them.

**Neither is fortified.**

There is an enemy crossbow. As far as i can tell, the unit does not have zone of control.

So why can't my units swap positions?
[image]

Comment: [This post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/312265473877948418/) kind of mentions the same things you've already said, but one person said the unit you are trying to move needs stamina, and one person said both units need the required amounts of movement points (I don't play Civ 6, so I don't know what any of that means - just reporting what I've found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently a bug that prevents ranged land units from swapping places. So someday, you'll be able to

Comment: Can you please provide a source for this claim?

Comment: @SGR nope, can't find any forum posts anywhere. Best I can do is say I've heard it all over the Civ VI LP community,  and one YouTuber (I don't remember which one and I've watched literally scores of Civ VI videos at this point) said he spoke to Firaxis and they're aware of it